# YouTube API comments streaming

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any YouTube API which enables external applications to search for keyword/brand name across all video comments on YouTube and send it back to some URL? Also, pull method is fine if the proposed push idea does not exist.

So I would like to know if my brand was mentioned in any video comment on YouTube, similar as what Twitter allows with User/Site Streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube API (v2.0) defines comments as a property of the video object. Details on this relationship here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments?hl=en#Retrieve_comments

Therefore, in order to search every YouTube comment you would need to traverse the entire collection of videos. If you're going to attempt something like this, it makes sense to validate your concept by first focusing on the feeds or categories that are most relevant to your brand. Details on feed and categories here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing

Comment: Hi there, answer is fine and I accepted it. Just to clarify: so I would need to a) get a list of all videos I am interested in, b) use API to get video properties, which include all the comments on a video, c) obviously process comments? Thank you for a great answer.

Comment: Yes, your statement of the process is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't anything like this available from the existing youtube api (neither V2 nor V3)